# Simple guessing game. "Your first guess is...."

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

I am creating this simple guessing game with three tries, but I need help adding code so it can display "First guess" followed by the integer the user puts in, "Second guess", etc... I currently just have "Enter your guess" which is the first try. What do I need to do? I'm confused on how to go about doing this. Sorry if the question is confusing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class guess {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int randomN = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int guess;
    System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 10.");
    System.out.println();
    int attempts = 0;

    do {
        attempts++;

        System.out.print("Enter your guess: ");
        guess = input.nextInt();

        if (guess == randomN) {
            System.out.println("You won!");
        } else if (guess < 1 || guess > 10) {
            System.out.println("out of range");
            attempts = +1;
        } else if (guess > randomN) {
            System.out.println("Too high");
        } else if (guess < randomN) {
            System.out.println("Too low");
        }

    } while (guess != randomN && attempts < 3);

    if (guess != randomN && attempts == 3) {
        System.out.println("Number is " + randomN);
    }


    }

}
```

Comment: `attempts = +1` should probably be `attempts += 1` or just `attempts++`.

Comment: `I need help adding code` In which part? Right after the user enters it? You want to output the user input? Or at the end of the run?

Comment: Store all answer in a ArrayList (``List<Integer> guesses = new ArrayList<Integer>();`` ) and print them after exit of while loop

Answer (score 0):

You could create another static method outside `main`, where you can output a custom message depending on the `attempts`.

```
public static String describe(int attempts) {
    switch(attempts) {
        case 1: return "First guess: ";
        case 2: return "Second guess: ";
        case 3: return "Third guess: ";
        default: return "Enter your guess: "; //should not happen
    }
}
```

Then in your `main` use it like so:

```
...
do {
    attempts++;

    System.out.print(describe(attempts));
...
}
```